The jq utility for Android, or some other command-line-based JSON parser?
We are writing some scripts to be run from the command line in Android, and JSON parsing is necessary. In Linux and other non-Android OS's, there's the jq utility, and we're trying to find something like this for Android.
We know that Java and Kotlin can do JSON parsing, but our work -- including the JSON parsing -- must be done solely via a command-line utility that's runnable within the Android shell processor through which we can pipe the JSON to be parsed.
We haven't been able to find anything like this, which is why we're posting this message here, in case someone can point us to this kind of JSON parser that we can use.
Thank you very much in advance.
